# Android MapView Draw Button on POI click

Tags: android, android-mapview

How can i do that?

When i click on a POI, i want to draw a button in the bottom of my mapview, with a setonclicklistener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to already have a button added to your layout and have the button not visible. Then when the user clicks on the POI you should show the button.